# Reloading page in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting started with reactJS and I'm trying to figure out how to refresh or redirect to another page after the user logs out. I have a logout component that logs the user out and redirects them to a logout page.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I'll give you an answer of equal value to this question `window.location.href = 'http://other.webpage.com/'`

Answer (score 0):

1.In order to refresh a page you can use `this.forceUpdate();`
 2.Redirect page after logout.
   Here i am using 'react-router'.

```
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;
var page=React.createClass({

render:function(){
<Link onClick={() => { Auth.logout() }} to="/signin">Logout</Link>
}
});
```

Comment: this will chage the url but not redirect to login page any idea ?

Comment: This could be due to your server not knowing how to resolve the URL. The one who knows which page to serve at a determined URL is ReactJS, but if you refresh, the first who tries to solve the routing is the server and thus, it redirects to 404 because it doesn't know nothing. I guess it could be solved making every URL in your app redirect to your app index. This way, server would send everything (that is not a file or a resource) to your ReactJS that would know, then, how to resolve the routing.

Comment: Maybe this could have something to do and could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually